# Nested Tiles with Wildcard Support

Tags: apache, tiles-3

Tile configuration :

---

```
<definition name="*/*/*/*/*/index" extends="defaultLayout.{1}.{2}.{4}">
    <put-attribute name="headerLocationPart" >
    <definition name="indexLocation"  template="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/layouts/LocationLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="location" value="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/location.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="subscriptionBtn" value="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/subscriptionBtn.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="indexPromo" value="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/indexPromo.jsp" />
        </definition>
  </put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/index.jsp" />
</definition>
```

---

When I m going to hit URL from my browser

> http://localhost:8080/etisalat/wap/mkportal/s/index.wfv

problem is Nested Definition "indexLocation" does not resolve {1},{2} parameter .

---

**Error is**

---

```
org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: JSPException including path '/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/layouts/LocationLayout.jsp'.
```

---

**So I need solution to pass wildcard value to resolve nested tile definition.**

Comment: Hi @mck can please provide ans for this problem, You are the one who solve my previous problem.

Comment: sorry for slow response. you should sign up and ask on the tiles user mailing list for quicker response times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous definitions can't have wildcards because they don't have names.

There is 2 different approaches you might take here
(i don't know which is correct for you because i don't know exactly what you are doing)

1)
You can use cascading="true" attributes instead of the additional definition like…

```
<definition name="*/*/*/*/*/index" extends="defaultLayout.{1}.{2}.{4}">
    <put-attribute name="headerLocationPart" template="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/layouts/LocationLayout.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="location" value="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/location.jsp" cascade="true"/>
    <put-attribute name="subscriptionBtn" value="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/subscriptionBtn.jsp" cascade="true"/>
    <put-attribute name="indexPromo" value="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/indexPromo.jsp" cascade="true"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/index.jsp" />
</definition>
```

2)
You can use a named definition like…

```
    <definition name="indexLocation.*.*"  template="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/layouts/LocationLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="location" value="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/location.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="subscriptionBtn" value="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/subscriptionBtn.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="indexPromo" value="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/indexPromo.jsp" />
    </definition>

<definition name="*/*/*/*/*/index" extends="defaultLayout.{1}.{2}.{4}">
    <put-attribute name="headerLocationPart" value="indexLocation.{1}.{2}"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/index.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Reference: http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/nesting-extending.html

Comment: The line `<put-attribute name="headerLocationPart" template="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/layouts/LocationLayout.jsp"/>` should be `<put-attribute name="headerLocationPart" value="/{1}/{2}/mkportal/s/layouts/LocationLayout.jsp"/>`.  `template` isn't a valid attribute for `put-attribute`